# NXT ARDOR wallet change over

Tags: nxt, ardor

I just bought ARDR and NXT on bittrex. I downloaded the wallet from nxt.org on to my laptop.

Can I send both Ardor and NXT from bittrex to this wallet? Has the Ign news happened?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Bitcoin.

Answer (score -1):

Ignis is still distributing until mid Nov-2017. You can send your nxt and ardor to you NXT wallet. Make sure you are NOT using the "Ardor client", as that is still in testing phase.

You send you nxt and ardor to you NXT address.